# Clarification about conditions for using Feynman's Integration Technique

Tags: integration

For the trick to work, we need to make sure beforehand that Leibniz's integral rule is satisfied, that is, given
\begin{equation}
\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt
\end{equation}
we need that both $f(x,t)$ and it's partial in $x$ are continuous in $x$ and $t$ for all $a(x) \leq t \leq b(x)$ and $x_0 \leq x \leq x_1$, for some $x_0, x_1$ (pulled from the wiki on [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)).

What confuses me is, when looking at the classic [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s1la_6e_T4) for using Feynman's trick to solve a tricky integral, namely
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2}-1}{\ln{x}}dx
\end{equation}
we find that before substituting in another variable in the integrand for the trick, although $\frac{x^{2}-1}{\ln{x}}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, its derivative diverges at $x=0$. Why are we allowed to use this technique on this integral?

Comment: The partial with respect to $y$ of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^y-1}{\log(x)}$ is $x^y$, which is continuous.

Comment: But the partial wrt x must also be continuous no?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article, the integration variable is $t$, not $x$.  In the example you stated, the dummy variable you used was $x$.  Change that $x$ to $t$

Comment: Ah right I see! Yeah it makes sens now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.